# Angular 6: Show / Hide component programmatically using @ContentChildren and @HostBinding?

Tags: angular

I want to create a tab component. This should be the end result:

```
<app-tab-container>
        <app-tab-item caption="A">..contentA..</app-tab-item>
        <app-tab-item caption="B">..contentB..</app-tab-item>
        <app-tab-item caption="C">..contentC..</app-tab-item>
</app-tab-container>
```

TabItemComponent has a @HostBinding('hidden') decorated field:

```
export class TabItemComponent {
    @HostBinding('hidden') isHidden = false;
    @Input() caption: string;
}
```

In TabContainerComponent I use @ContentChildren to iterate through tab-items :

```
export class TabContainerComponent {
    @ContentChildren(TabItemComponent) items: QueryList<TabItemComponent>;
    tabItems: string[] = [];

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.items.forEach((item, idx) => {item.isHidden = true; this.tabItems.push(item.caption));
    }
}
```

Finally TabContainerComponent template is as follows :

```
<div class="tab-title"
     *ngFor="let caption of tabItems">{{caption}}</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

The end goal is to toggle the visibility of a tab-item via click event.

When I run the code tab titles display correctly but the content itself (app-tab-item caption="A" to "C") is still visible, setting isHidden doesn't toggle visibility.

Please note that I don't know the number of "app-tab-item" components, since I may place the "app-tab-container" elsewhere with different content.

How can I programmatically toggle visibility of `<app-tab-item>` components using @ContentChildren ?

Comment: `When I run the code tab titles display correctly but the content itself (app-tab-item caption="A" to "C") is still visible` Can you reproduce it with stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry, not this time, because I had to 'dumb' down the code a lot. But nevertheless I found a solution to the problem. @HostBinding('class.hidden') @Input() hidden = false;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of trying to set the [hidden] attribute, I now set a '.hidden' css class. It works as expected :

```
export class TabItemComponent {
    @HostBinding('hidden') isHidden = false;
    @Input() caption: string;
}
```

I used this code + css class :

```
export class TabItemComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.hidden') @Input() hidden = false;
    @Input() caption: string;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```